# Fetch data from Access by comparing dates using WHERE Date BETWEEN start date and end date chosen from JQuery DatePicker

Tags: php, jquery, ms-access, jquery-ui-datepicker

currently for my system , i am creating a php chart system where user can select desired date from two datepickers which is start date and end date.

Once user submit the dates, the dates will be stored into variables as $From and $To using $_POST. I would like to take these two dates can fetch data from my Access database.

Below is my current code

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
        $From=$_POST['From'];
        $To=$_POST['to']; 
        $conn = odbc_connect("Ingot_Daily_Report", "", "");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN '$From' AND '$To'";
        $sql = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
        while($row=odbc_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>  
        ["<?php echo $row['data_Day']; ?>", <?php echo $row['Crystal_Out']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Aggressive_Daily_Target']; ?>, <?php echo $row['KPI_Target']; ?>, <?php echo $row['AverageToDate']; ?>],
    <?php   
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**My DatePicker Code**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'
    });
    $(function(){
        $("#From").datepicker({
             
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             $("#To").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

        }

        });
        $("#To").datepicker({
            
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);

                }
        });
    });
               
});
</script>
```

My Access Date column is in Date/Time type but when i run the above code, there will be an error showing Datatype mismatch. Ive tried to set the column to long text however , the data shown is not as I wanted because for example i chose date 15/6/2021 till 17/6/2021 the data fetch will be all the data that have dates between 15-17 , the query totally ignored the month and year, this is the case when i change my column to long text, when i change to date/time , error datatype mismatch comes out.

Someone please help me.

Comment: Your database would have YYYY-MM-DD format. so you need to re-format the date to make it work.

Comment: @Samir That is for SQL but not the case for Access, i chose short date which is dd/mm/yy

Comment: Format setting means nothing. Access stores dates as a double number and by default translates it to mm/dd/yyyy unless your system and database are set up for international date style of dd/mm/yyyy. Format setting on field does not alter the actual value. I seldom do formatting in table because of the confusion it creates.

Comment: @June7 can you guide me on this issue ? How to address this error correctly? Is it possible to compare dates that i set as string ?

Comment: Comparing dates as strings only works if they have same number of characters so need placeholder zeros: 09/01/2021. Because this is alpha sorting, comparing one character at a time. I don't program in PHP nor use international date style so really don't know how to best address. A query in Access expects dates to be delimited with # characters, text with apostrophes, and numbers don't have delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Try using octothorpes, the date/time delimiter for Access SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN #$From# AND #$To#";
```

Comment: It still give me datatype mismatch Sir. My column in Access is in Date/Time datatype

Comment: And what values do `$From` and `$To` hold?

Comment: They are dates taken from Jquery Datepicker.

Comment: Yes, but what are the final values exactly?

Comment: This is what i echo out 
6/17/2021 (From)
6/19/2021 (To)

Comment: Then criteria is `BETWEEN #6/17/201# AND #6/19/2021#` which is valid if `data_Day` is of data type DateTime. If that fails, something else is going on.

Comment: It only shows datatype mismatch when i try to fetch data. Frustrating

Comment: Double-check. Your posted SQL cannot fail.

Comment: It just failed Sir, can you kindly create a working example with php and access so that i can refer please ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't; my knowledge in PHP coding is _nil_.